# How to access row's data via onClick in <td> element?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-table

In the below shown Users.jsx file I am populating a table with the data stored in the userList array. I have implemented an onClick listener in a table data cell element, I want the Trigger function to be called with the clicked row's info object. Or I want to be able to access the clicked row's data in the Trigger function.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Navbar from "../components/NavBar";
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';

function Users() {

  let userList = [
    {'name': 'Jack',
    'age': 21,
    'role': 'Customer',
    },
    {'name': 'Tom',
    'age': 22,
    'role': 'Product Manager',
   }]

   const Trigger = () => {
     // Here
   }
  
  const UserData = userList.map(
    (info)=>{
      return(
          <tr>
          <td>{info.name}</td>
          <td>{info.age}</td>
          <td>{info.role}</td>
          <td onClick={Trigger}> Visit Profile  </td>
        </tr>
      )
    }
  )

  return(
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <Table striped bordered hover responsive="md">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>AGE</th>
                    <th>ROLE</th>
                    <th>PROFILE</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {UserData}                    
                </tbody>
            </Table>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Users;
```

Any help with a solution or recommendation to documentation for (event handlers needed in this context) will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Users() {

  let userList = [
    {'name': 'Jack',
    'age': 21,
    'role': 'Customer',
    },
    {'name': 'Tom',
    'age': 22,
    'role': 'Product Manager',
   }]

   const Trigger = (info) => {
    // info it's user obj
   }
  
  const UserData = userList.map(
    (info)=>{
      return(
          <tr>
          <td>{info.name}</td>
          <td>{info.age}</td>
          <td>{info.role}</td>
          <td onClick={()=>{Trigger(info)}}> Visit Profile  </td>
        </tr>
      )
    }
  )

  return(
    <div>
      <Navbar/>
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
            <Table striped bordered hover responsive="md">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>AGE</th>
                    <th>ROLE</th>
                    <th>PROFILE</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {UserData}                    
                </tbody>
            </Table>
            </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}

export default Users;
```

Comment: Some explanation of your solution would make this answer better. See [answer].

Answer (score 2):

An arrow function call would do the job:

```
   let userList = [
    {'key': 1,
    'name': 'Jack',
    'age': 21,
    'role': 'Customer',
    },
    {'key': 2,
    'name': 'Tom',
    'age': 22,
    'role': 'Product Manager',
   }]

   const Trigger = (info) => {
     // Here
     console.log(`Name is: ${info.name}, Age: ${info.age}, Role: ${info.role}`)
   }
  
  const UserData = userList.map(
    (info)=>{
      return(
          <tr key={info.key}>
          <td>{info.name}</td>
          <td>{info.age}</td>
          <td>{info.role}</td>
          <td onClick={() => Trigger(info)}> Visit Profile  </td>
        </tr>
      )
    }
  )
```

P.S
I've added keys to the list to avoid warnings..